# Autoprefixer script doesn't run TypeError: Patterns must be a string or an array of strings

Tags: css, npm, sass, postcss, autoprefixer

I installed autoprefixer and postcss-cli successfully. I am trying to "Set up a simple build process with NPM scripts" using my command prompt and VS code. I am watching a tutorial on CSS/SASS topics as I only have 2 months of coding experience and don't quite understand how to debug yet. I completed the code I wanted and now I am trying to compile everything into a compressed style.css doc... I successfully concatenated everything but now I am having trouble with prefixing.

In the command prompt I am typing: `npm run prefix:css` which is running this script:
`postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css`

I get:

```
TypeError: Patterns must be a string or an array of strings 
 at assertPatternsInput (C:\Users\mjpry\Desktop\advanced-css-course master\Natours\starter\node_modules\globby\index.js:17:9)
    at generateGlobTasks (C:\Users\mjpry\Desktop\advanced-css-course-master\Natours\starter\node_modules\globby\index.js:42:2)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\mjpry\Desktop\advanced-css-course-master\Natours\starter\node_modules\globby\index.js:116:20)
    at C:\Users\mjpry\Desktop\advanced-css-course-master\Natours\starter\node_modules\postcss-cli\index.js:59:14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! natours@1.0.0 prefix:css: `postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 10 versions' css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the natours@1.0.0 prefix:css script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mjpry\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-29T23_00_22_951Z-debug.log
```

Like I said.... not enough experience to even start solving this. Id suspect that it isn't the Node_Modules that is the problem like what this error seems to be catching... but I don't know what to do regardless. Help please!

[Screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhxMa.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using windows (and you do as you paths show) try the following:

`postcss --use autoprefixer -b \"last 10 versions\" css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css`

From: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20048

Comment: Okay...that worked.So windows just didn't understand the single quotes? 

 I appreciate it! Apparently I need to improve on my search skills as well.